# after grouping to minimum value in pandas, how to display the matching row result entirely along min() value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The dataframe contains

```
>> df
        A          B            C
A
196512  196512    1325  12.9010511000000
196512  196512  114569  12.9267705000000
196512  196512  118910  12.8983353775637
196512  196512  100688  12.9505091000000
196795  196795   28978  12.7805170314276
196795  196795   34591  12.8994111000000
196795  196795   13078  12.9135746000000
196795  196795   24173  12.8769653100000
196341  196341  118910  12.8983353775637
196341  196341  100688  12.9505091000000
196641  196641   28972  12.7805170314276
196641  196641   34591  12.8994111000000
196346  196341  118910  12.8983353775637
196346  196341  100688  12.9505091000000
196646  196641   28980  12.7805170314276
196646  196641   34591  12.8994111000000
```

I tried to get minimum value for each group and display using the following code,

```
df.columns = ['a','b','c']
df.index = df.a.astype(str)
dd=df.groupby('a').min()['c']
```

it gives the result

```
196512    12.7805170314276
196795    12.7805170314276
196341    12.7805170314276
196346    12.7805170314276
```

but after grouping, I want to get the row with the minimum 'c' value, grouped by column 'a' and display that full matching row in result 
like,

```
196512    118910      12.8983353775637  
196795     28978      12.7805170314276
196341     28972      12.7805170314276
196346     28980      12.7805170314276
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this. But I doubt the efficiency.

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,3,3],'b':[4,5,6,3], 'c':[1,2,3,5]})
>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  1
1  1  5  2
2  3  6  3
3  3  3  5
>> df[df['c'].isin(df.groupby('a').min()['c'].values)]
   a  b  c
0  1  4  1
2  3  6  3
```

Comment: This does not work unless c is also unique.

Comment: This solution doesn't work if there are multiple minimums in "C" and if "C" has a floating-point number such as `3.0875E-09` to `0.0000000030875`.

Answer (score 29):

In case this can help anyone else. Here is a solution that is more computationally efficient.

### TL;DR version

If each row already has a unique index, then do this:

```
>>> df.loc[df.groupby('A')['C'].idxmin()]
```

If you've already indexed by 'A', then convert 'A' back into a column first.

```
>>> df2 = df.reset_index()
>>> df2.loc[df2.groupby('A')['C'].idxmin()]
```

---

Step by Step explanation:

### Step 1.

First, make sure each row in your dataframe is uniquely indexed. This is the default when importing csv data. e.g.

```
    >>> df = pd.read_csv('questionData.csv'); df
        A       B       C
    0   196512  1325    12.901051
    1   196512  114569  12.926770
    2   196512  118910  12.898335
    3   196512  100688  12.950509
    4   196795  28978   12.780517
    5   196795  34591   12.899411
    6   196795  13078   12.913575
    7   196795  24173   12.876965
    8   196341  118910  12.898335
    9   196341  100688  12.950509
    10  196641  28972   12.780517
    11  196641  34591   12.899411
    12  196346  118910  12.898335
    13  196346  100688  12.950509
    14  196646  28980   12.780517
    15  196646  34591   12.899411
```

Aside: If you already converted column 'A' into an index, then you can turn the index back into a column (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461165/how-to-convert-pandas-index-in-a-dataframe-to-a-column) by doing: `df.reset_index()`

### Step 2.

Use the [pandas.DataFrame.idxmin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) function to retrieve the indices of the minimum of each group.

The semantics of the example below is this: "group by 'A', then just look at the 'C' column of each group, and finally return the index corresponding to the minimum 'C' in each group.

```
>>> indices = df.groupby('A')['C'].idxmin; indices
A
196341     8
196346    12
196512     2
196641    10
196646    14
196795     4
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

### Step 3.

Finally, use the retrieved indices in the original dataframe using [pandas.DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to get the rows of the original dataframe correponding to the minimum values of 'C' in each group that was grouped by 'A'.

```
>>> df.loc[indices]
    A       B       C
8   196341  118910  12.898335
12  196346  118910  12.898335
2   196512  118910  12.898335
10  196641  28972   12.780517
14  196646  28980   12.780517
4   196795  28978   12.780517
```

Note: The groupby('A') operation returns groups sorted by A. Thus 'indices' is sorted by A. If we want the original order, we just have to do

```
>>> df.loc[indices].sort_index()
    A       B       C
2   196512  118910  12.898335
4   196795  28978   12.780517
8   196341  118910  12.898335
10  196641  28972   12.780517
12  196346  118910  12.898335
14  196646  28980   12.780517
```

Comment: Eg. "C"= [`3.0875E-09,3.0875E-09,3.0875E-09,3.1079E-09,3.1109E-09,3.9361E-08,4.3794E-08,4.3794E-08,4.7742E-08`]. For this, your idxmin() returns 3 rows with "C"=[`4.3794E-08, 4.7742E-08, 3.0875E-09`], instead of returning `[3.0875E-09,3.0875E-09,3.0875E-09]` or just `3.0875E-09`. Any suggestions why?

Answer (score 5):

First check your data. You can't get value **12.780517** for index **196341**. This value will be for index **196641**.

Now, to get column **'b'** in your result, use **pd.merge**. Don't make column **'a'** as index. Leave it as it is.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[196512, 196512, 196512, 196512, 196795, 196795, 196795, 196795, 196341, 196341, 196641, 196641, 196346, 196346, 196646, 196646],'b':[1325 , 114569 , 118910 , 100688 , 28978 ,34591 , 13078 ,  24173 , 118910 , 100688 , 28972 , 34591 , 118910 , 100688 , 28980 , 34591 ],'c':[12.9010511000000 ,12.9267705000000 ,12.8983353775637 ,12.9505091000000 ,12.7805170314276 ,12.8994111000000 ,12.9135746000000 ,12.8769653100000 ,12.8983353775637 ,12.9505091000000 ,12.7805170314276 ,12.8994111000000 ,12.8983353775637 ,12.9505091000000 ,12.7805170314276 ,12.8994111000000 ]})
>>> df1 = df.groupby(['a'])['c'].min()
>>> df1
a
196341    12.898335
196346    12.898335
196512    12.898335
196641    12.780517
196646    12.780517
196795    12.780517
Name: c, dtype: float64
```

df1 is a series type object here. Convert it to dataframe.

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1, columns = ['c'])
```

Also, make index of df1 as column **'a'** and change index.

```
>>> df1['a'] = df1.index
>>> df1.index = range(df1.shape[0])
>>> df1
       c       a
0  12.898335  196341
1  12.898335  196346
2  12.898335  196512
3  12.780517  196641
4  12.780517  196646
5  12.780517  196795
```

Now you have to join this **df1** with **df** on both columns **'a'** and **'c'**.

```
>>> pd.merge(df,df1, on = ['a','c'])
    a       b          c
0  196512  118910  12.898335
1  196795   28978  12.780517
2  196341  118910  12.898335
3  196641   28972  12.780517
4  196346  118910  12.898335
5  196646   28980  12.780517
```

And you have your output as desired!

Comment: This solution also works if there are multiple minimums in "C"